# Invalid postback or callback argument. what is the issue with this code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have this gridview and i don't know what is the problem with the buttons inside it.
I have this asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUsername" Text='<%# Eval("cUserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept User" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDept" Text='<%#  iif(Eval("lDeptUser"),"Yes","No")  %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="black" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button  ID="btnedit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" OnClick="DeleteRow" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And when i press delete or edit on any row it gives me error!! `Invalid postback or callback argument.`

This is my server side code in vb.net:

```
Public Function GetList() As DataTable
    Dim Query As String = "Select cUserName,lDeptUser FROM Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators"
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Query, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        gvList.DataSource = dt
        gvList.DataBind()
        Return dt
    End Using

End Function

Public Function DelRow() As DataTable

    Dim strusername As String = CType(gvList.FindControl("lblUsername"), Label).Text.Trim()

    Dim Query As String = "Delete FROM Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators where cUserName='" & strusername & "'"
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Query, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Adapter.Fill(dt)
        Return dt
    End Using

End Function

Protected Sub DeleteRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    DelRow()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GetList()

End Sub

Protected Sub gv(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvList.RowDataBound
    e.Row.Cells(3).Visible = False
    e.Row.Cells(4).Visible = False


End Sub

End Class
```

I think that its from the client side. Please help me with this problem.
btw i am not using any ajaxtoolkit till now and the `EnableEventValidation="true"` in the page as well as the web.config

What is the problem and its solution, please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: First i would wrap the code in _Page_Load_ in a `If Not IsPostBack Then GetList()`.

Comment: it works ! but when i press on delete button it gives me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the `Dim strusername As String = CType(gvList.FindControl("lblUsername"), Label).Text.Trim()` line.

Comment: Dont you need to handle this in the RowCommand event and check if CommandName=Delete. Then perform delete and in there rebind it. You should also put the initial bind in a postback check If Page.Ispostback = false then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would wrap the code in `Page_Load`:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then GetList()
```

So you just want to databind the grid on the first load and not on postbacks. It's state will be maintained via `ViewwState` by default.

The next problem in `DeleteRow`, you are trying to find the label via `FindControl` on the `GridView`. But the `NamingContainer` of it is the `GridViewRow` since a `GridView` contains multiple rows(and labels) not just one.

So you have to get the reference to the row first. Just use the `NamingContainer` of the `Button`:

```
Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim row = DirectCast(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
Dim lblUsername = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblUsername"), Label)
' ... '
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this function call. Because

```
CType(gvList.FindControl("lblUsername"), Label).Text.Trim()
```

is only allowed on the button click event. So do the function code inside your button click event itself.