# invalid postback or callback argument gridview imagebutton

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am facing very strange issue when clicking on gridview image button.I've tried almost all solutions found on google but none of them help me to sort out the issue.

when I click on image button on gridview it gives following error "invalid postback or callback argument "

I am also binding gridview in !IsPostback code block .but still it gives same error.

following is my code block

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       if (Request.QueryString["res"] != null && Request.QueryString["res"].ToString() == "200")
       {
           DisplayMessage(true, MESSAGE_DISPLAY_TYPE.SUCCESS);
       }

        this.LoadData();
       }               
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
   {
    Logger.LogMessageToDB("Error - " + ex.Message, PageName, "ManageSpecials:" + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
   } 

   private void LoadData()
   {
    try
     {
       DataSet objDS = Special.GetSpecialList();
       gvSpecial.DataSource = objDS.Tables[0];
       ObjSortDataTable = objDS.Tables[0];

       gvSpecial.DataBind();

      }
        catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Logger.LogMessageToDB("Error - " + ex.Message, PageName, "ManageSpecials:" + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
   }
    }

 protected void gvSpecial_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
   try
    {
     if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
      {
        string cID = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
        Response.Redirect("AddSpecials.aspx?do=edit&id=" + cID, false);
       }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
     {
        int cID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int intReturnValue = Special.DeleteSpecial(cID);

  if (intReturnValue > 0)
      {
        this.DisplayMessage(true, MESSAGE_DISPLAY_TYPE.SUCCESS);
        this.LoadData();
        gvSpecial.DataBind();
       }
     }
    }
     catch (Exception ex)
    {
     Logger.LogMessageToDB("Error :- " + ex.Message, PageName, "ManageBanners :" + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
     }
   }
```

here is gridview image button I used

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="grid_button" />
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' AlternateText="Delete" ToolTip="Delete Special" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?\nIf you delete then all data related to this specials will also be deleted.');" />
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

can anyone help me sort out this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405964/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-what-is-the-issue-with-this-code

Comment: Post your GridView Markup, especially show  the ImageButtons

Comment: @sandy Can you tell us on which particular line of code you are getting this error?

Comment: when I click on this button.it gives me error.